# Union of Polymorphic and Non-Polymorphic Types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, polymorphism, flowtype

The way Flow anticipates polymorphism is really causing me a headache. [Here's a minimum example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgB2cATgLYCGMAggMYYCWchYAvGAN6oCQ2+AXGADOGEg0IBzADSowcsDgpZ4FACYB+QRUJYZAX3R8COODCxlSOABYNadRszAAeAAqCQAPjadZYI4JExSRk5RWU4NUEXfUNcAgp6JhZ2EzMLEmtbeySnTzAAHyJSShpE5gBudFpmETAyLGzmLTLkn144wQAiAAk8GHhOkLBuMJVVQQ4wAGs8LC6AdVIYVU6wAz1K1GrCWvqXU3NLGzsW5odCJ3rGwhclMYAVOK92LnaBMB6+gaGRu4jxzjTWYLJYrNaoAyYOJ1BotW7hNSPfDeV4zOZEACuZAARngSBCgA) to demonstrate the trouble I'm having.

I would expect the following to throw an error based on having the incorrect type for `myPolymorphicAction.payload.key`. Instead, it's choking on `action` not being a polymorphic type.

Is Flow able to tell the difference here?

```
/* @flow */

type normalAction = {
    type: string,
    payload?: any,
}

type polymorphicAction <P: *> = {
  type: string,
  payload: P,
}

type action = polymorphicAction<*> | normalAction;

const myAction: action = {
    type: "Hello",
    payload: { key: "World" }
};

const myPolymorphicAction: action<myActionPayloadType> = {
    type: "Hello",
    payload: { key: "World" }
}

type myActionPayloadType = {
    key: number
}

// FLOW OUTPUT //

20: const myPolymorphicAction: action<myActionPayloadType> = {                                                             
^ object literal. Expected polymorphic type instead of

20: const myPolymorphicAction: action<myActionPayloadType> = {
                               ^ type `action`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Expected polymorphic type

means that you are using `<...>` on a type that isn't polymorphic. Since your `action` is

```
type action = polymorphicAction<*> | normalAction;
```

Flow is correct, your `action` type doesn't have `<>` on it. You could do

```
type action<T> = polymorphicAction<T> | normalAction;
```

and then

```
const myAction: action<*> = {
// ...
const myPolymorphicAction: action<myActionPayloadType> = {
```

which will make Flow stop throwing the error you are getting, but that will still not cause it to error on your `"Hello"` string because your action has `| normalAction` and `normalAction` still has `payload?: any,` which will allow any payload.